# What relevance do p-values have in a multiple regression of all 50-states (a.k.a. population/census data)

Tags: multiple-regression, feature-selection, regression-coefficients, population, stepwise-regression

I am running a regression analysis of the U.S. (specifically, the population represented in the U.S. Congress by voting members, so census data for the 50 states would constitute population data). One of the predictors comes back with a univariate regression p-value of 0.8+. Also, step-wise addition of other variables shows the p-value decreasing as variables are added but log transform on the dv for the model with all variables increased. The final values are: no-transform: An F test p-value < 0.0001, an R² ≈ 0.6 and an RSME of around .75, and a p-value of the coefficient in question of ≈0.089. the p-value from 0.089 to ≈0.25 and reduced the RSME from ≈0.75 to ≈0.68 og transforms of the DV brought the Coefficient p-value down to around .25 and the RSME to 0.06, and R² ≈ 0.55. The results passed brausch-pagan test, Ramsey’s RESET test for omitted variables, VIF test, the residuals pass Shapiro-Wilk test of normality. The linear and quadratic regression curves for residuals vs fitted plot had near 0 R² value. Removal of the variable negligibly decreases R² and negligibly increases RSME. F-Test p-value is still near zero.

Normally that would be cause to remove the variable from the model, or at least consider it. However, my understanding is that p-values and SE values have no meaning for population data. It seems wrong that if I took a random subsample and got these results, I would likely conclude that that they aren’t meaningful. But with population data there’s no error from sampling. Do I ignore the SE or is it a sign that there’s other forms error?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What do you want to learn from your data analysis? Typical statistics can get funky when you have the whole population (no more uncertainty), but gathering the entire population is hard, and I am not convinced that your data truly represent populations with zero uncertainty.

Comment: @Dave, in general, I can see your point about uncertainty, but it so happens that the variable in question is literally and indisputably population data as it is a scale measure of number of the state house and houses of state legislature controlled by democrats in 2020. I.e. Arizona would be 0 but Cali is 3. As for the DV, infant mortality rate, is the rare instance where the entire target population is, for all practical purposes, captured in the reporting. One other variable is also indisputably population data (a scale indicating whether the state mandates family leave, unpaid and paid).

Comment: @Dave Though, I suppose this does raise a question about the question of significance's significance. As the point of multiple regression is to hold the other variables constant, if one assumes that your assertion about uncertainty is correct (I honestly don't know either way), would that only apply to the variables based off of aggregated sample. I.e., if Educational attainment and poverty rate are subject to error, would that suddenly make the p-value relevant? I

Comment: Also, ironically, after correcting some data entry errors, the stated p-value is now 0.053 for the variable in question in the full model and significant for all nested models with that var. Also a linear transform of the DV to make it percent and not per mil fixed the RSME without impacting the p-values.  I think I will provide the values both with and without that variable and explain why I left it in.

Comment: You seem to de doing stepwise regression. Look through some of the posts on this site about stepwise: [tag:stepwise-regression]!